# awk to parse field by using period and output unique digits

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to parse `$2` on using the first `.` in the string and output the digits with the header row above it. The current output is close but both commands seem to taking `$1` as well.  Do I need to specify something in the command to only prints the digits in `$2`, it seems close. Thank you :).

**file**

```
R_2016_09_20_12_47
IonXpress_007 16-0001.xxx.xxx
IonXpress_008 16-0002.xxx.xxx
IonXpress_009 16-0003.xxx.xxx
R_2016_09_20_12_46
IonXpress_007 16-0004.xxx.xxx
IonXpress_008 16-0005.xxx.xxx
IonXpress_009 16-0006.xxx.xxx
```

**desired output**

```
R_2016_09_20_12_47
16-0001
16-0002
16-0003
R_2016_09_20_12_46
16-0004
16-0005
16-0006
```

**awk**

```
awk -F. '{print $1}' file
```

**cut**

```
cut -d'.' -f1 file
```

**current output**

```
R_2016_09_20_12_47
IonXpress_007 16-0001
IonXpress_008 16-0002
IonXpress_009 16-0003
R_2016_09_20_12_46
IonXpress_001 16-0004
IonXpress_002 16-0005
IonXpress_003 16-0006
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
% awk -F'[ .]' '{print $2 ? $2 : $1}' file                                                                     

R_2016_09_20_12_47
16-0001
16-0002
16-0003
R_2016_09_20_12_46
16-0004
16-0005
16-0006
```

#### NOTE

- i take space and `.` as separators
- i use *ternary operator* to make a condition on `$2`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanations :)